# Why do I get an ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set') when running from Windows Server, but not when running on my dev machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, active-directory, windows-server

I am developing an Node/Express app, which will use ActiveDirectory.  The login form posts the username and password to a /auth route, which does the AD authentication, and sets some values in the req.session.  This block is the function in question, it works perfectly from my Windows 10 dev machine, but when I move this code to a Window Server, it fails with the error seen below.

***Follow up:*** I have confirmed that this is only a problem when using the LDAPS/TLS for the Active Directory module of choice. I actually have two version of this project, using different Active Directory modules. Both of them have the same error ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT when using LDAPS/TLS.

If I revert them to non-secure connections or run it from my dev. machine.  No issue.

```
http_app.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
    
    req.body.username = `${req.body.username}@${APP_DOMAIN}`;

    ad.authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, auth) {
        if (err || !auth) {
            req.session.authenticated = false;
            res.status(401).send(`Login failed, please <a href="/">try again.</a>.<br /><br /><details><summary>Technical</summary>${JSON.stringify(err)}</details>`);
            return;
        } else if (auth) {
            req.session.authenticated = true;
            req.session.userPrincipalName = req.body.username;
            //it fails on either of these lines, but only when running on a Windows Server
            //res.status(200).send(`<a href="/app">Ok!!!</a>`);
            res.redirect('/app');
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

When I move all of the code to a Window Server for testing, I get this error during the login process.  There are no differences that I am aware between environments, they're using the same version of Node, and all of the same node_modules files:

```
Listening on *:80
(node:3304) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTP
S requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:_http_outgoing:649
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:649:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\username\Desktop\cet\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\username\Desktop\cet\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/cet/app/server.mjs:350:33
    at Client.handleError (C:\Users\username\Desktop\cet\node_modules\activedirectory\lib\activedirectory.js:1817:14
)
    at Client.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at TLSSocket.onSocketError (C:\Users\username\Desktop\cet\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1001:12)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v20.1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.

I discovered there was a weird factor involving my VPN connection that no one in my organization could explain.  The code was working if my dev. machine was connected to the VPN, and not working when on-premises.  There are a lot of factors in play here, include some funky TLS decrypt stuff our info sec. team is doing on the network. I decided to leave that gremlin alone and just focus on how to actually fix the issue.  And I did two things to solve it:

1. Added our self-signed CA to and domain cert to the ActiveDirectory object.  It didnt work to tell Node to just blindly trust the connection, it always failed.  If your org uses self signed certificates, ask for a copy of the certs in the CA chain.

```
//set the global ad value to an ad connection using the saved service account
ad = new ActiveDirectory({
    url: `ldaps://${APP_DOMAIN}:636`,
    baseDN: `${APP_BASEDN}`,
    username: ad_service_account,
    password: ad_service_account_password, 

    //add CA certs here:
    tlsOptions: {
        cert: fs.readFileSync('domain-cert.cer'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('certificate-authroity-cert.cer'),
    },
});
```

2. I rewrote the auth middleware function, and /auth end-point like this:

```
//Middleware function for Express, to update the session with an authenticated flag.

function AuthMiddlewareFun(req, res, next) {
    console.log('AuthMiddlewareFun Timestamp: ' + (new Date().toTimeString()));

    ad.authenticate((`${req.body.username}@${APP_DOMAIN}`), req.body.password, function(err, auth) {
        console.log('AuthMiddlewareFun() Error Check: ' + (new Date().toTimeString()));

        if (err) {
            console.error('AuthMiddlewareFun() error: ', err);
        }

        if (auth) {
            console.log('AuthMiddlewareFun() success: ' + (new Date().toTimeString()));
            req.session.authenticated = true;
            req.session.userPrincipalName = req.body.username;
        }

        return next();
    });
};

http_app.post('/auth', AuthMiddlewareFun, function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.session.authenticated) {
        return res.redirect(`/fail`);
    }
    return res.redirect(`/app`);
});
```

There is still a weird thing happening with my request routing because the AuthMiddlewareFun() is getting called twice every time, but the second time it generates and error that we trap so ultimately it works.